# Git how to push different working copies to different bare repos

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I've run into a problem when I try to push only the new files I created to a different bare repository.

Say, I had two bare repository: **repo1.git**  and **repo2.git**

1. I clone a copy of repo1.git and create a new file called test_repo1.txt
2. I push test_repo1.txt to the origin (repo1.git)
3. I now create another file called test_repo2.txt
   I want to push **ONLY** test_repo2.txt from my repo1.git working copy to repo2.git   repository.

So, I ran the following commands under my repo1.git working copy.

```
git add test_repo2.txt
git commit -m "add only test_repo2.txt file to repo2.git"
git push repo2.git master:master
```

Once I did the above commands,

I went in to the **repo2.git** working copy and find out that "**test_repo2.txt**" file is there but "test_repo1.txt" file is also there as well which is not what I want. I only want "test_repo2.txt" to be there not "**test_repo1.txt**".

Why did the "**test_repo1.txt**" file end up in the **repo2.git** bare repository ?

Your help will be much appriciated.

Thanks

Finau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` pushes commits by following branches, not individual files. In your case you have two commits, the commit for `test_repo1.txt`, and the commit for `test_repo2.txt`, but each is in the same branch.

When you `git push` to `repo1` after adding `test_repo1.txt`, the branch only has your commit for repo one. However, once you do `git add test_repo2.txt` and commit it, the **same branch** now has both commits, so both changes are applied to `repo2` when you push.

To accomplish what you want to do, you will need to have two branches in your local working copy, let's call them `branch_repo1` and `branch_repo2`. You will `git push` each branch to its respective repo. Your procedure is this:

1. `git clone repo1` as before, and `git checkout master` (or whatever branch you want to start from)
2. `git checkout -b branch_repo1` to create and check out a branch for your `repo1` changes.
3. `git add test_repo1.txt` and `git commit` and `git push repo1 master` (replacing `master` by whatever branch on `repo1` you want to push to)
4. `git checkout master` again to go back to your starting branch (which will not have the commit for `test_repo1.txt`)
5. now repeat: `git checkout -b branch_repo2` to create a branch for your `repo2` changes.
6. `git add test_repo2.txt` and `git commit` and `git push repo2 master`
7. Done. `repo1 master` will have the commit you put in the `branch_repo1` branch, and `repo2 master` will have the commit you put in the `branch_repo2` branch.

**Note** that in your `git push` you must specify not only which repo but which *branch* you want to push to. Assuming you are working from `master` on both, you would want to do:

```
git push repo1 master # while you have the branch_repo1 branch checked out
```

and

```
git push repo2 master # while you have the branch_repo2 branch checked out
```

This will accomplish what you want to do.

(final note: I named the branches with a prefix of `branch_` instead of just `repo1` and `repo2` to avoid repo name/branch name ambiguity. You can name the branches whatever you want).

Comment: Hi shelhamer, excellent!! thanks so much for your time. much appriciated mate.  cheers!

Comment: @Finau, no problem! Have fun with git.

Comment: if you use newer version of git, it should give a warning on push

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ, could you comment further as to the exact warning? Did I type out a command too hastily?